# how to return a generic data type (Temple) from class function

Tags: kotlin

I want to return a value from class variable through a function using generic data type such temple but I don't know how to do that.

i'm trying to use a template data type in function and return this value from function.

```
class di<T>(crea:T){
    var h:T=crea
    init{
        println("your class is ready")
    }
    fun diplay:<T>{
        return h
     }
}
fun main (args:Array<String>){
    var he2 =di<Int>(23)
    println(he.diplay())

}
```

These type of errors are occurring.
Error:(6, 15) Kotlin: Expecting '('
Error:(7, 16) Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is T but Unit was expected

Comment: hahahahah i'm just want to know how to use stack overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, you are simply using wrong syntax

```
class di<T>(crea:T){
    var h:T=crea
    init{
        println("your class is ready")
    }
    fun diplay(): T{
        return h
    }
}
fun main (args:Array<String>){
    var he2 =di(23)
    println(he2.diplay())
}
```